# Nested decorators? (Python)

Tags: python, decorator

I've discovered that I can decorate a function in two different ways to achieve the same "decoration" on the function:

```
def greeting(expr):
    def greeting_decorator(func):
        def function_wrapper(x):
            print(expr + ", " + func.__name__ + " returns:")
            func(x)
        return function_wrapper
    return greeting_decorator

def foo(x):
    return x

greeting2 = greeting("Good morning!")
foo = greeting2(foo)
```

or...

```
def greeting_decorator2(func, expr):
    def function_wrapper(x):
        print(expr + ", " + func.__name__ + " returns:")
        print(func(x))
    return function_wrapper

def foo(x):
    return x

foo = greeting_decorator2(foo, "Good morning!")
```

Note that the first example can be changed to use the "at"-notation:

```
@greeting("Good morning!")
def foo(x):
    return x
```

but using the at-notation with the second decorator function example causes a crash, and understandably so.

My question is, which one of these methods of including additional arguments to the decorator function apart from the function to be wrapped is to be preferred? The second one seems easier to wrap one's head around, and possibly more scalable if one needs more additional arguments. Are there any downsides to using it?

Comment: The downside is that it’s not a decorator. Decorator syntax looks really nice.

Comment: Does it have to use ´@decorator_name`-syntax to be considered a decorator? For all intents and purposes it behaves like a decorator, right?

Comment: It’s just a normal function. Also, decorator arguments aren’t “one nested function per parameter”; rather, the decorator is the entire expression following `@` and the value of the expression is always called. If you had two arguments it would just be `def greeting(expr, expr2)`.

Comment: Yeah, I came to realise that, too about the parameters. I suppose I'll stick to standard "at"-notation then!